# Django Admin + Filter Horizontal?

Tags: django, django-admin

I've added [filter horizontal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

```
filter_horizontal = ('blocked_email_notifications',)
```

To my `ModelAdmin`, but it's still rendering it as a multiple select widget, rather than the nifty javascript enhanced version. How come? Do I need to add something else?

The user model has it defined as

```
blocked_email_notifications = ManyToManyField('EmailTemplate', blank=True)
```

And the form has it defined as

```
blocked_email_notifications = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=EmailTemplate.objects.order_by('key'), required=False)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you define the field in the form you need to include the widget:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple

blocked_email_notifications = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=EmailTemplate.objects.order_by('key'), 
    required=False,
    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
        verbose_name=EmailTemplate._meta.verbose_name,
        is_stacked=False))
```

`is_stacked`:

- `False`: the lists are rendered side by side
- `True`: the lists are rendered one underneath the other

Comment: Just want to add to the answer that you will need to pass an instance of FilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name, stacked) instead of the class so recent versions of Django don't complain.

Comment: Hope this helps too http://blog.jayapal.in/2009/08/reuse-django-admin-filteredselectmultip.html